Milvus Lite Insert with Duplicate IDs Does Not Overwrite Existing Data
When inserting data with the same ID into Milvus standalone, it overwrites the existing data if the ID already exists. However, this behavior does not occur in Milvus Lite, where multiple entries with the same ID are persisted. Can you explain the difference in behavior between Milvus Lite and Milvus standalone regarding this issue?
from pymilvus import connections, Collection, CollectionSchema, FieldSchema, DataType

connections.connect(alias="default", host="localhost", port="19530")

id_field = FieldSchema(name="id", dtype=DataType.INT64, is_primary=True)
vector_field = FieldSchema(name="vector", dtype=DataType.FLOAT_VECTOR, dim=128)
schema = CollectionSchema(fields=[id_field, vector_field])

collection = Collection(name="example_collection", schema=schema)

ids = [1, 1]
vectors = [[0.1]*128, [0.2]*128]

collection.insert([ids, vectors])

collection.load()
results = collection.search([[0.15]*128], "vector", params={"metric_type": "L2", "params": {"nprobe": 10}}, limit=10)
print(results)


It would be great if you show what printed for results
